# python datetime not the correct format

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, datetime

I get python exception that my string date time does not match but I can't see what's wrong

```
ValueError: time data '2017-08-25T02:19:53.000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2017-08-25T02:19:53.000` doesn't match `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ` because it doesn't have the Zulu (`Z`) ending.

Instead the format would just be `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f`.

From `ipython`:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: do = datetime.strptime('2017-08-25T02:19:53.000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

In [3]: do
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 25, 2, 19, 53)
```